# JS: build function and multidim array; then build loop to display array contents in sentence form and prompt user for values where content is missing

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie to JavaScript and would be very grateful for some guidance in accomplishing the following task (which has three parts) as I keep getting stuck. From reading through other questions and answers on this site, I'm thinking there may be more than one way of doing it. I would really like to learn what the *most efficient and valid approach* to take would be.

Thanks so much for steering me in the right direction (and for being patient with my egregious beginner's mistakes and misconceptions!)

*The directions:*

- a) Build a function “iPaid” that accepts three parameters: month, utility and amount. It outputs something like “On [month], I paid $[amount] for [utility].” using the console.log function. Utilities paid each month include water, gas, and electricity.
- b) Build a two dimensional array that contains a row for month, and a column for water and gas. Put the amounts paid in the corresponding utilities. (I know, I left electricity out).
- c) Build a loop over the months. Call iPaid to display what you paid, using the content in arrays. For each electricity bill, use the window.prompt function to get the amount paid from the user.

*What I've got so far:* (a whole lotta nuthin'...) :-(

a) Is this correct? Or am I way off base?

```
iPaid = function(month, utility, amount) {
    this.month = month;
    this.utility = utility;
    this.amount = amount;
console.log("In " + this.month + " I paid $ " + this.amount + " for " + this.utility + ".");
};
```

Perhaps it will need to be something like:

```
iPaid = function(month, utility, amount) {
    this.month = month;
    this.utility = utility;
    this.amount = amount;
console.log("In " + month[i] + " I paid $ " + amount[i][j] + " for " + utility[j] + ".");
};
```

b) How do I go about building the two-dimensional array? And do I need to leave room for "electricity?

Like this?

```
var myBills = new Array(12,2); 
    myBills[0][0] = new iPaid("January","water",45);
    myBills[0][1] = new iPaid("January","gas",15);
```

Or should I define month, and utility separately so it's more like this? (I don't think this syntax is correct, though)

```
var myBills = new Array(12,2); 
    myBills[0][0] = (month[0],[utility[0],45);
    myBills[0][1] =
```

c) Is this anything close to the correct way to do the prompt? Or should I define electricity as utility[2]? Do I need to use a "push" to add it to the array?

```
for (var i = 0; i < month.length; i++) {
  var electricity = prompt("What did you pay for electricity in " + month[i] + "?", "");
return(electricity);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
var MONTHS = [
  "January", 
  "February",
  "March",
  "April",
  "May",
  "June",
  "July",
  "August",
  "September",
  "October",
  "November",
  "December"
];

var UTILITIES = [
  "electricity",
  "water"
];

var iPaid = function(month, utility, amount) {
    this.month = month;
    this.utility = utility;
    this.amount = amount;
}

var myBills = [];

for (var month = 0; month < MONTHS.length; month++) {
  for (var utility = 0; utility < UTILITIES.length; utility++) {
    if (!(myBills[month] instanceof Array)) {
      myBills[month] = [];
    }
    var amount = 10; // Fill this from propt or whatever.
    myBills[month][utility] = new iPaid(MONTHS[month], UTILITIES[utility], amount);
  }
}

for (var month = 0; month < myBills.length; month++) {
  for (var utility = 0; utility < myBills[month].length; utility++) {
    console.log("In " + MONTHS[month] + " I paid $" + myBills[month][utility] + " for " + UTILITIES[utility] + ".");
  }
}
```

[Link to codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/teJCg)

I don't think the `new Array(12,2)` was doing what you expected. In JavaScript you typically allocate arrays by just iterating through and assigning values. A two dimensional array requires a nested loop.